# Relation between the "s" parameter of Ungar's theory of hyperbolic geometry and the eccentricty in the 2D case

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, conic-sections

In Ungar's theory of hyperbolic geometry for the Minkowski model, there is a parameter $s>0$ which controls the curvature of the hyperbolic segments:

[image]

Ungar's theory is not very well-known. An intro and a reference can be found [on my blog](https://laustep.github.io/stlahblog/posts/hyperbolicPolyhedra.html).

I'm wondering whether this parameter $s$ is related to the eccentricity in the 2D case? Would you know? In fact I have the classical equation of a hyperbola and I wonder whether I can get $s$ from this equation, not necessarily a one-one relation with the eccentricity.

The reason I'm interested in this question is that I'm currently playing with the additively weighted Voronoï tessellations, whose edges are hyperbolic segments, and using Ungar's theory is the easiest way to plot these edges I think. But maybe it is computationally easier to get the eccentricty than $s$.

[image]